# Does https include protection from a replay attack?

Tags: security, ssl, https

Is it possible to perform a replay attack on a request transfered via https?  Meaning, does the https protocol enforce a mechanism similar to [digest access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) where a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) is introduced into the request to prevent replay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, it does .
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft02.html

HTTPS calls nonce connection id and its 128 bits long.

Comment: So the answer is yes it is possible to perform a replay attack but the SSL protocol makes it sufficiently improbable in real-world scenarios to make replay attacks near impossible to perform.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct, as the mode of authentication selected for HTTPS sets up it's ability to prevent a man-in-the-middle  or replay attack.  For the most part, yes, it does.  But there can be implementations of HTTPS which do not protect against a replay attack.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the implementation of HTTPS.  It indeed can be secure against a replay attack - for instance in an RSA key exchange, a temporary key is created which prevents execution of a replay attack.  However, a anonymous key exchange does not provide replay protection, I believe.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ssl-version3-00  Appendix F